# html, file uploading trouble

Tags: html, file, forms

I have a trouble with file-uploding. Here is my part of the form:

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" />
<input type="submit" name="add_new" value="Upload" />
```

And in script i have a code:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

After image choosing and sending form, I have an empty array $_FILES. Why?

Comment: What language is this? That's probably the most important tag for you to have on a post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form must be set like this:

```
<form action="myuploadpage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

So that the browser knows to send the image along with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the form method to POST data to the PHP script and set the action to point to it? If so then you should be able to get something like $_FILES['image_file']['name']